# Odd jQuery behavior in IE

Tags: jquery

I have a span element that replaces a checkbox so I can style it. I also have a label tag; when clicked it should fire the span's click event as if the user has just clicked the span element.  In other words - I'm mimicking the label/checkbox relationship with label/span.

This functionality works as intended in Firefox and Chrome but not IE.  In IE 7 and 8, clicking the label does nothing and seems to generate some odd attribute in the source:

```
<span class="checkbox" id="Vechicle-1" jQuery15105041923284548672="2"/>
<label class="large text-left" for="Vechicle-1" jQuery15105041923284548672="24">
```

In IE 9 I do not see the jQuery string appended and 2x clicking the label will fire off the span's click event.

```
$('.checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');

    if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $('#checkbox-' + $(this).attr('id')).attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('#checkbox-' + $(this).attr('id')).removeAttr('checked');
    }
});

$('label').click(function () {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).click();
});
```

Any idea what's causing this behavior?

Comment: Post the code that you're using to *generate* the label -- it looks like that's where the problem is (in particular, it looks like you are generating the IDs for the checkbox and putting a space in them).

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: Are you using some jQuery plugin or extension? If so please specify which exactly.

Comment: No jQuery plugins or extensions here; v1.5.1

Comment: jQuery attaches attributes to elements whenever you add event handlers. Many browsers won't show these when you view the source.

Comment: No problem. If you want to see exactly what gets added, you call `.data()` on a jQuery collection and log it to the console in Firebug or Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the click event is bubbling upwards and trigger some other code you might have, try to prevent it by changing the code to:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    //......
```

And the same for the other click handler.

Edit: found the root of this behaviour. As it turns out, IE browser "let" label affect non form elements as well, including `<span>` meaning that clicking label element will trigger the `click` event of the element having ID defined as the label `for` attribute - no matter what is the element type.

Chrome (and probably Firefox) would let it trigger only form elements like checkbox, as expected.

Proof of this can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KZm5c/1/) just browse with IE browser (even 9) and see the span is "clicked" when label is clicked even though the jQuery line is commented.
(Code in fiddle is the same as in the original question)

All this boils down to the interesting conclusion: clicking the label caused the span to be clicked twice - one time by the browser and another by jQuery code, causing it to toggle its state twice.

Comment: Also, I only had to add the preventDefault to the label.

Comment: Taught me something new too, so my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to put your `$('.checkbox').click` code within an external function, which can then be called when the user clicks on either the checkbox or the label:

```
function checkboxClick(checkboxElement){
    checkboxElement.toggleClass('checked');

    if (checkboxElement.hasClass('checked')) {
        $('#checkbox-' + checkboxElement.attr('id')).attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('#checkbox-' + checkboxElement.attr('id')).removeAttr('checked');
    }

}

$('.checkbox').click(function () {
    checkboxClick($(this));            
});

$('label').click(function () {
    checkboxClick($('#' + $(this).attr('for')));
});
```

Comment: I used your method instead.  It doesn't solve my problem but thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the `for` attrubute and find the element. You can try to use `prev` method which will give you the `span` element and the call `click` method on it.

```
$('label').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IE doesnt behave nicely when you try to set the attribute checked through javascript and this bug has always bitten me in my arse. The easy way that I was able to fix this was to remove the inout element entirely and replace it with a new input element with the attribute checked="checked" set and that works..

```
var $checkedItem= $(selectorForCheckedBox)


$checkedItem.clone().addAttr("checked","checked").insertAfter('span.checkbox');
$checkedItem.detach();  //$checkedItem.remove() use it appropriately.
```

Hope this helps. lemme knoe if you find a easier fix.. a comment would help//